# lambda unexpected results

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following simple python code

```
numbers = range(1,100)
print (list(numbers))
numbers_over_30 = filter(lambda x: x>>30,numbers)
print (list(numbers_over_30))
```

I create a list of numbers from 1 to 99 and that works fine giving me

```
[1,2,3,4,5.....97,98,99]
```

the second list should give me

```
[31,32,33....97,98,99]
```

but I only get an empty list `[]`.

If I change the lambda function I get as below:

```
x>>5 gives me [32,33,34...97,98,99]
x>>4 gives me [16,17,18...97,98,99]
x>>3 gives me [8,9,10...97,98,99]
```

Can anyone shed some light on what the lambda function is doing? I expected that `numbers_over_30` would consist of all values of numbers for which `x>>30` was true?

I'm sure there are better ways to do it but I'm specifically trying to achieve the result using filter and lambda per a CodeAcademy unit so am just trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: Your variable is called `numbers_over_30` but the filter has nothing to do with that. `>>` is a bitwise operation.

Comment: `>>` is a binary shift operation. It filters out all numbers with fewer than 30 bits.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo. You can delete the question if that's all it was.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a typo, I was using >> instead of > because I thought >> was correct.  Do I delete the question?

Comment: As a debugging hint, looking at what x >> 30 was actually returning could have made this much clearer much earlier.

Comment: Why did you think `>>` was correct? What resource suggested that `>>` was a comparison operator?

Comment: Can't say really, checking now it's not C or Java...I think I've used it that way in something.  Still learning here so pardon my error.  Joshua, l did, x>>30 was giving me an empty list.  How would I have determined the result was being bitwise shifted to oblivion?

Comment: @AzzaClazza Joshua is suggesting to try only `x>>30`, for some value of x, not the whole iteration. For example, `20 >> 30` and `100>>30` both return 0. First, it is not a boolean but a number. Then, 20 and 100 both lead to the same value, whereas a comparison should give different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to delete one >, so your code will be :

```
numbers = range(1,100)
print (list(numbers))
numbers_over_30 = filter(lambda x: x>30,numbers)   # here your error
print (list(numbers_over_30))
```

Comment: This adds no new or useful information over the older answer. In fact, it has less information, with no explanation of what's happening.